# Is there a way to download and use an app from Google play store with the creators of the app getting any information about me?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, privacy

Basically without the app knowing anything about my Google account and consequently anything else other than the information I directly provide it.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Phone is rooted.

Comment: Unless you perform an "sign in with Google" within the app and you don't purchase something within the app and pay via Play Store the app is not linked to your Google account at all.

Comment: Ah OK. But what info can it pull?

Comment: If you sign-in with Google within the app Google shows you what data the app want to access.

Comment: Your question is very broad. There are a number of ways an app can collect and send your information over internet. Two most common cases are 1) the app collecting and sending the info itself. This can be simply prevented by using a firewall. 2) App using Google Play Services APIs e.g. (Firebase for push notifications, ads or analytics etc.). In this case you need to isolate your app from the Google account.